# Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel dagger2

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger

Cannot create an instance of class FacebookViewMdel.
dispatchingAndroidInjector and viewModelFactory  return nullobject reference.
trying to make facebook ligin page using dagger .

```
    public class FacebookActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IOnRequestCompleted,
        RestFinishLoginWithFbInterface,HasActivityInjector,RestPostAllContactInterface {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Inject
    ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;

    private FacebookViewModel viewModel;



     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

       viewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(FacebookActivity.this,viewModelFactory).get(FacebookViewModel.class);


FacebookViewModel.class

    class FacebookViewModel
@Inject constructor(
        application: Application,
         val appRepository: AppRepository
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    fun signInWithCustomToken(token: String): Completable =
            appRepository.signInWithCustomToken(token)

    fun setCurrentUser(user: User) {
        appRepository.setCurrentUser(user)
    }
}
```

> ```
>  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.miracas.groupgiri/com.miracas.groupgiri.ui.facebook.FacebookActivity}:
> ```
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class
>   com.miracas.groupgiri.ui.facebook.FacebookViewModel
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2792)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1601)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.miracas.groupgiri.ui.facebook.FacebookViewModel
>           at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:201)
>           at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134)
>           at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102)
>           at com.miracas.groupgiri.ui.facebook.FacebookActivity.onCreate(FacebookActivity.java:115)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1601) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6590) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class android.app.Application]
>           at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2320)
>           at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1725)

Comment: i think the issue is with dagger otherwise with the constructor

Comment: Can you post code of `ViewModelFactory` for `FacebookViewModel`?

Comment: I don't see where you are actually calling `inject()`